# Using mask to replace string in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, mask

If I have an array that looks like ar, which is an numpy array? How can I use numpy mask to replace all "replaceme" with 2012.

```
ar = [['replaceme', 1,2], ['replaceme', 3,4],['replaceme', 5,6]]

ar = [[2012, 1,2], [2012, 3,4],[2012, 5,6]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a job for masks so much as [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ar = np.array([['replaceme', 1,2], ['replaceme', 3,4],['replaceme', 5,6]], dtype=object)
>>> ar
array([[replaceme, 1, 2],
       [replaceme, 3, 4],
       [replaceme, 5, 6]], dtype=object)
>>> ar == "replaceme"
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

and so all we need to do is:

```
>>> ar[ar == "replaceme"] = 2012
>>> ar
array([[2012, 1, 2],
       [2012, 3, 4],
       [2012, 5, 6]], dtype=object)
```